# Why a SELECT result is repeated 4 times?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these tables:

[image: Table 1]

[image: Table 2]

When i try to make a select between them getting the `APELLIDO` column:

```
SELECT APELLIDO FROM EMP, DEPT WHERE (EMP.DEPT_NO = 30);
```

it shows the correct information but it´s repeated 4 times!!!
Why is this happening? Isn´t it correct? Another fact is that if i use this other sentence

```
SELECT APELLIDO FROM EMP WHERE DEPT_NO IN (SELECT DEPT_NO FROM DEPT WHERE DEPT_NO = 30);
```

it´s displayed correctly but why does the other command make that? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  **Always use proper, explicit, *standard* `JOIN` syntax:**.

However in your case, you don't even need a `JOIN`.  All the information is in `EMP`:

```
SELECT EMP.APELLIDO 
FROM EMP
WHERE EMP.DEPT_NO = 30;
```

The `,` operator does a `CROSS JOIN` -- a full Cartesian product.  There is no reason to do this for these two tables.

Comment: Thank you, that was the explanation i was wanting. Thanks and sorry for the inconveniences.